# How to get disk statistics in the Postgres' Cloud SQL?

Tags: postgresql, google-cloud-sql

We are having performance issues in our database probably connected to the disk performance (maximum read MB/s). Therefore, I want to see some statistics of the disks. However, there is no such statistic:
[image]

Comment: Hi, this is the only metric that it's not shown the correct information  ?

Comment: What do you mean by the only metric? This metric doesn't exist anyway :D.

Comment: Yes, there are other metrics such Storage usage, Memory usage ..... :)

Comment: So yeah: I have all other metrics, but this metric doesn't exist.

Comment: I recommend you open a [Cloud Support ticket(https://cloud.google.com/support-hub) in order that they verify your project and your instance and provide further advice.